# How to get a text inside of a span with a class. (inside of for loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, innerhtml

I would like to get a text inside of a span which has a class `move`. So I am trying to make that when you click the button, its text inside of a class move is passed to a function `move` as one of the arguments. p.s. the HTML code is given, and I cannot change anything on it. Is there something wrong in my js code? The error message says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined".

part of HTML code;

```
 <div id="my-card">


    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="moves">
          <button>
            <span class="move">a</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">b</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">c</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
          <button>
            <span class="move">d</span> <span class="dp"></span>
            <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="weakness" class="weakness" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
               document.querySelectorAll("#my-card .moves button")[i].onclick = function(){ move(document.querySelectorAll("#my-card .moves .move")[i].innerHTML, gameID, playerID) };
     }
```

Comment: you forgot to close off (`</span>`) some of your `<span>`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll("#my-card .moves button")[i].onclick = 
       function(){ move(this.querySelectorAll(".move")[0].innerHTML, gameID, playerID) };
 }
```

I switched your `document.querySelectorAll` to `this.querySelectorAll`.

Below is a snippet showing the results to the console.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("#my-card .moves button")[i].onclick = function() {

    console.log(this.querySelectorAll(".move")[0].innerHTML)

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="my-card">


  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="moves">
        <button>
          <span class="move">a</span> <span class="dp"></span>
          <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
        </button>
        <button>
          <span class="move">b</span> <span class="dp"></span>
          <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
        </button>
        <button>
          <span class="move">c</span> <span class="dp"></span>
          <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
        </button>
        <button>
          <span class="move">d</span> <span class="dp"></span>
          <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="Pokemon move" />
        </button>
      </div>
      <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="weakness" class="weakness" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, your code worked, but im wondering why I have to use 0 as an index in 'this.querySelectorAll(".move")[0].innerHTML'. Why don't you use i??

Comment: Because **i** is on the button, setting up the click event. **this** gets invoked once the button is clicked. At that point it queries for your selector which may be a few so we are selecting the first one.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you so much!